# How to remove all characters after "-" or "("

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm working on MySQL Workbench 8.0. And I would like to remove all the characters after "-" or "("

```
Organic Rice Sticks - Spinach OR Organic Rice Sticks (Pack of Three)
```

To

```
Organic Rice Sticks
```

Does MySQL have the functionality to do this?

EDIT: I would also like to remove the characters after "[" such as Organic Rice Sticks [Pack of Three] to Organic Rice Sticks

Comment: workbench is a client; what matters (though not for this question) is the version of the server, which doing `select version();` will show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select substring_index(substring_index(mysterycolumnname, '-', 1), '(', 1)
```

Though given your sample data, you want to actually remove characters after `' -'` or `' ('`.  Or remove trailing spaces:

```
select rtrim(substring_index(substring_index(mysterycolumnname, '-', 1), '(', 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Select SUBSTRING(ProductName, 1, LOCATE(' ', ProductName) - 1) from Products

You can try above [here](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_instr)

Comment: That will produce "Organic" from the sample data, not the desired "Organic Rice Sticks".  It will also produce an empty string if there are no spaces, which makes substring/locate a poor choice for this kind of problem.