# Extract characters from a products list containing "[", "-", "(" with different positions

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm working on MySQL 8.0 and I wanted to extract characters from my data.

There are variations within the same product such as flavors, prices including shipping or not, size, etc.

The data includes the following products.

| Product | Total |
| --- | --- |
| Organic Rice Snacks - Apple | 6 |
| Organic Rice Snacks - Rice | 5 |
| 62-Sam Almond Crisp Jujube - 20g | 4 |
| 62-Sam Almond Crisp Jujube - 20g (members-only) | 5 |
| [Sale] Extra Virgin Sprouted Perilla Oil Best Before 9/3 or 9/11/2021 (160ml) | 3 |
| [Sale] Extra Virgin Sprouted Perilla Oil Best Before 9/3 or 9/11/2021 (300ml) | 3.5 |
| [Steak Family Set 4] Ribeye 12 oz. x 4 (Never frozen) | 20 |
| [Steak Family Set 4] Ribeye 12 oz. x 4 (Shipping Included) | 21 |
| Ecomom Sangol Organic Rice Snacks (Pack of Three) | 6 |
| Ecomom Sangol Organic Rice Snacks - Apple | 7.5 |

And I would like to find the following result by grouping the variants of the products:

| NewProduct | GTotal |
| --- | --- |
| Organic Rice Snacks | 11 |
| 62-Sam Almond Crisp Jujube | 9 |
| [Sale] Extra Virgin Sprouted Perilla Oil Best Before 9/3 or 9/11/2021 | 6.5 |
| [Steak Family Set 4] Ribeye | 41 |
| Ecomom Sangol Organic Rice Snacks | 13.5 |

I tried the following but it doesn't apply to the whole data.

```
Select  rtrim(substring_index(substring_index(substring_index(Product, '-', 1), '(', 1), '[', 1)) as NewProduct, SUM(Total) as GTotal
From myData
Group By NewProduct
```

Could anyone help me solve this problem? I'd really appreciate it.

P.S. I asked a similar question on another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75883506/how-to-remove-all-characters-after-or) but I realized my data is much more complicated.

Comment: In "NewProduct" you're leaving some bracket. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the brackets in [Sale] and [Steak Family Set 4] can be left as they are. I would like to remove the last parts showing size, members only, or type and combine the products.

Comment: I would suggest you to introduce a new column that has this grouping data entered manually. There is no common logic between these product names that you could use to perform the grouping to your requirement. Even if we come up with a logic for  these specific rows, there is no guarantee that a future product name will not break it.

Answer (score 0):

as Shadow pointed out, there is no common logic between these product names that you could use to perform the grouping to your requirement. You'll never get it with pure SQL. But luckily we are here to help!

You can't group it for sure by removing some unallowed character and characters between them, but you can recursively check for occurrences between your product names, gradually including a greater part of the string. That needs some code to be achieved, here you have a python script that do the job

```py
import sqlite3


class Product:

    UNALLOWEDS = ["-", "(", ")", "[", "]"]

    def __init__(self, id, name, amount):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount
        self.normalizations = 0
        self.substr1 = ""
        self.substr2 = ""

    def normalize(self, products):
        occurences = 0
        positions = list()

        for unallowed in Product.UNALLOWEDS:
            if self.name.find(unallowed) != -1:
                positions.extend([i for i, letter in enumerate(self.name) if letter == unallowed])

        for _ in range(self.normalizations):
            positions.pop(positions.index(min(positions)))

        positions = [i for i in positions if i != -1]
        if not len(positions):
            return self.id, self.name, self.amount

        substr = self.name[0:min(positions)].strip()
        for product in products:
            if product.id != self.id:
                if product.name.startswith(substr):
                    occurences += 1

        if occurences and len(positions) > 1:
            self.normalizations += 1
            self.substr2 = self.substr1
            self.substr1 = substr
            return self.normalize(products=products)
        elif not occurences and self.substr2 and not self.name[0] in Product.UNALLOWEDS:
            return self.id, self.substr2, self.amount
        elif not occurences and self.substr1:
            return self.id, self.substr1, self.amount
        else:
            return self.id, substr, self.amount


if __name__ == "__main__":
    products = list()
    normalizeds = list()

    con = sqlite3.connect("prod.db")
    cur = con.cursor()

    for row in cur.execute("SELECT * FROM products"):
        products.append(Product(row[0], row[1], row[2]))

    for product in products:
        normalized_data = product.normalize(products=products)
        normalizeds.append(Product(normalized_data[0], normalized_data[1], normalized_data[2]))

    for normalied in normalizeds:
        print(normalied.id, normalied.name, normalied.amount)

    con.close()
```

I created the following table called **products** under a sqlite3 db

| id | name | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Organic Rice Snacks - Apple | 6.0 |
| 2 | Organic Rice Snacks - Rice | 5.0 |
| 3 | 62-Sam Almond Crisp Jujube - 20g | 4.0 |
| 4 | 62-Sam Almond Crisp Jujube - 20g (members-only) | 5.0 |
| 5 | [Sale] Extra Virgin Sprouted Perilla Oil Best Before 9/3 or 9/11/2021 (160ml) | 3.0 |
| 6 | [Sale] Extra Virgin Sprouted Perilla Oil Best Before 9/3 or 9/11/2021 (300ml) | 3.5 |
| 7 | [Steak Family Set 4] Ribeye 12 oz. x 4 (Never frozen) | 20.0 |
| 8 | [Steak Family Set 4] Ribeye 12 oz. x 4 (Shipping Included) | 21.0 |
| 9 | Ecomom Sangol Organic Rice Snacks (Pack of Three) | 6.0 |
| 10 | Ecomom Sangol Organic Rice Snacks - Apple | 7.5 |

Running the above code on the table printed out the following result:

```
1 Organic Rice Snacks 6.0  
2 Organic Rice Snacks 5.0  
3 62-Sam Almond Crisp Jujube 4.0  
4 62-Sam Almond Crisp Jujube 5.0  
5 [Sale] Extra Virgin Sprouted Perilla Oil Best Before 9/3 or 9/11/2021 3.0  
6 [Sale] Extra Virgin Sprouted Perilla Oil Best Before 9/3 or 9/11/2021 3.5  
7 [Steak Family Set 4] Ribeye 12 oz. x 4 20.0  
8 [Steak Family Set 4] Ribeye 12 oz. x 4 21.0  
9 Ecomom Sangol Organic Rice Snacks 6.0  
10 Ecomom Sangol Organic Rice Snacks 7.5
```

Of course, you're using a mysql db, so adapt the connection part in a mysql supported way. Also, that's not giving back your grouped table, but it's creating a list of *"Normalized"* objects, please notice that it should be very easy to write those objects as records in a table and execute all your desired queries after.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**
While that could be a solution, consider that your situation is a pure mess. First things first you should consider to have a dedicated table to your products, a very basic **product_id --> product_plain_name** and the use those ids as foreign keys where needed. Modifiers, such as *frozen, pack of three, members-only, exc* should be applied apart, you can use another foreign key column with the same approach used above: **modifier_id --> modifier_name**. Integer column where every number matches a specific modifier in the code could be another valid solution. One last thing, my code **does not scale**, that could do the job with a few hundred records, but it can't clearly handle milions. Search for db design and normalization for an in depth explanations.

Hope it helps,
Hele.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(product, '(', ' - '), ' - ', 1)) AS NewProduct,
       SUM(total) GTotal
FROM test
GROUP BY 1
```

| NewProduct | GTotal |
| --- | --- |
| Organic Rice Snacks | 11.00 |
| 62-Sam Almond Crisp Jujube | 9.00 |
| [Sale] Extra Virgin Sprouted Perilla Oil Best Before 9/3 or 9/11/2021 | 6.50 |
| [Steak Family Set 4] Ribeye 12 oz. x 4 | 41.00 |
| Ecomom Sangol Organic Rice Snacks | 13.50 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OAeLYH0k)

Comment: Your solution does not match the expected outcome for ribeye (row 4)...

Comment: @Shadow I don't see any logic in pruning names at all. OP could not formulate an exact and unambiguous set of rules. When he does, I will be able to make corrections to the expression.

Comment: Yeah, this is why I refrained from answering in the first place. However, you fo not point out these problms in your snswer.